# Create JOIN for a many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I can't get my head around JOIN and many-to-many database relationships.

I have 3 tables (structure has been simplified)

**USERS:**

```
id (primary)    |    userEmail    |    userName    |    userAddress    |    userCreated
```

**TEAMS:**

```
id (primary)    |    teamName    |    teamLogo    |    teamCreated
```

**TEAMS-USERS**

```
id (primary)    |    userId    |    teamId    |   userLevel
```

Teams can have many Users. And Users can be in many Teams. The UsersTeams table tracks which users are in which teams (note: I'm not using foreign keys or anything).

When a user logs in, I want to get a list of all the teams they are a member of and the corresponding data i.e.

- get the data from USERS (where id = $id)
- look it up in TEAMS-USERS
- get the team information from TEAMS via the teamID in TEAMS-USERS
- store it all in one array

I have this code so far but to be honest I'm just trying lots of variations:

```
    $model->select('users.*, teams.*, teams.id as teamId, teams-users.id as teamsUsersId, teams-users.userId as teamsUsersUserId, teams-users.teamId as teamsUsersTeamId');
    $model->where("users.id", $id);
    $model->join('teams-users','teams.id = teams-users.teamId','inner');

    $data = $model->get()->getRowArray();
```

Running the query above gives me the error: **Unknown table 'myproject.teams'** - even though the TEAMS table 100% exists and I use it throughout my project.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You join the same table twice... each needs its own, unique alias, or the database cannot distinguish between them..

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because in your query you are not including a from clause and you are missing a join clause. With codeigniter you can do that like:

```
$model->select('users.*, teams.*, teams.id as teamId, teams-users.id as teamsUsersId, teams-users.userId as teamsUsersUserId, teams-users.teamId as teamsUsersTeamId');
//$model->where("users.id", $id);
$model->join('teams-users','teams.id = teams-users.teamId','left');
$model->join('users','user.id = teams-users.userId  and users.id='.$id,'left');
$data = $model->get('teams')->getRowArray();
```

explanation:

- there was a missing join of table users
- you want to use left joins
- place the where clause inside the corresponding join (it becomes `and`)
- you missed the from part, which can be done placing the table name in
  the get() function or by `$model->from('teams');`

see also this [nice explanation of joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Thanks @Vickel. I had to remove 'teams" from ```get()``` and add a FROM clause (teams) but it works. Sort of. It should return 2 rows. However, it returns 5 (the 2 matches just repeated). 5 is also the number of rows in my reference table teams-users. Any reason why this would happen?

Comment: Actually, no it's just listing all the rows in the team-users table. The where statement is being ignored